# Github Oauth using Chrome Web apps issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm trying to authenticate to github using my Chrome web app.

When I click on the button, I get the callback and I get this error in console.

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.launchWebAuthFlow:
>   The user did not approve access.

**popup.js**

```
var githubButton = document.getElementById('github');
githubButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var CLIENT_ID = "da1d7c12a3ab20decba5";
    var CALLBACK_URL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");
    var AUTH_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize/?client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&redirect_uri='+CALLBACK_URL+'&scope=notifications';
    // Opens a window to initiate GitHub OAuth, fires callback
    // with token in the URL.
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: AUTH_URL,
        interactive: true,
    }, function(redirectURL) {
        var q = redirectURL.substr(redirectURL.indexOf('#')+1);
        var parts = q.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var kv = parts[i].split('=');
            if (kv[0] == 'access_token') {
                token = kv[1];
                console.log('token is', token);
            }
        }
    });
}, false);
```

**Manifest.json**

```
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "*://*.github.com/*"
   ],
```

**index.html**

```
<button id="github">Github</button>
```

Not really sure where I'm going wrong :-( Please kindly enlighten me!

I just want to get to `access_token` so that I can do some `POST` requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) might help you

**Get access tokens**

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // Use the token.
});
```